# show that $u(r e^{i \theta}) = \theta \log r$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{C} \setminus (- \infty , 0]$.

Tags: harmonic-functions

My attempt to show that $u(r e^{i \theta}) = \theta \log r$ is harmonic is the next: if $z = r e^{i \theta}$ we have $\log z = \log r + i \theta$, then ${(\log z)}^2 = {(\log r)}^2 + i 2 \theta \log r - {\theta}^2 = {(\log r)}^2 + i 2 u(z) - {\theta}^2$; that means that $u(z) = \frac{Im [(\log z)^2]}2 = Im \varphi$, where
$$
\varphi(z) = {\left(\frac{\log z}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}^2
$$
As $\varphi$ is holomorphic and $u$ is the imaginary part of $\varphi$, then $u$ is harmonic.

Do you think that my argument is correct?

Comment: Why is it well-defined?

Comment: That seems sensible to me

Comment: I meant defined in $\mathbb{C} \setminus (- \infty , 0]$, I modified it

Comment: I think your solution is correct - the proposed function in the complex plane is holomorphic and single-valued (if you do not cross the cut $(-\infty;0]$) - its reat and imaginary parts are harmonic functions. You can also check directly, using Laplace equation in polar coordinates ($\hat L=\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}r\frac{d}{dr}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}$)

Comment: how can I see this?